# How to implement __eq__ in shapely (python)

Tags: python, shapely

I have a question regarding [shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/) and the usage of `==` operator. There exists a function to test equality of geometric object: `.equals()`. However `==` does not work.

```
Point((0, 2)).equals(Point((0,2))
```

returns True.

However:

```
Point((0, 2)) ==  Point((0, 2))
```

returns False

I would like to be able to use the `==` operator to check if a `Point` is already present in a list. One use case could be:

```
if Point not in list_of_points:
    list_of_points.append(Point)
```

As far as I understand, this does not work because `==` returns `False`. I know there exists alternative to `in` by using the `any()` function, but I would prefer the `in` keyword:

```
if not any(Point.equals(point) for point in list_of_points):
    list_of_points.append(Point)
```

Would it be a large effort to implement `__eq__` in the `shapely/geometry/base.py`?
What do you think of this naive implementation of `__eq__`?

```
class BaseGeometry(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.equals(other)
```

or

```
class BaseGeometry(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return bool(self.impl['equals'](self, other))
```

Comment: Why don't you try it out? Your analysis is spot on and your first implementation looks entirely correct to me.

Comment: Thanks, here is the implementation: [link](https://github.com/antoinepairet/Shapely) I have tested it locally on my machine and it seems to work well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current Shapely (2.x), geometries are hashable out-of the box.

> Geometries can be used as **elements in sets or as keys in dictionaries**. Python uses a technique called hashing for lookups in these datastructures. **Shapely generates this hash from the WKB representation**. Therefore, geometries are equal if and only if their WKB representations are equal.
> [...]
> Comparing two geometries directly is also supported. This is the same as using `shapely.equals_exact()` with a tolerance value of zero.

The official docs on that topic: https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/geometry.html#hashing, which also document some gotchas of Shapely hashing.

Answer (score 0):

One side effect of implementing `__eq__` is that a Point can no longer be a key in a dictionary.  If you want that feature, you can add this:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(id(self))
```

Comment: Thanks, here is the implementation: https://github.com/antoinepairet/Shapely          I have tested it locally on my machine and it seems to work well

Comment: No. The implementation of `__hash__` should make sure that equal elements have same hash, i.e. `a == b` implies `hash(a) == hash(b)`. This is *not* true if you use this implementation for `__hash__`. It the OP case he could simply do something like `def __hash__(self): return hash(self.x) + hash(self.y)`. There are probably much better hash functions then this, but at least this satisfies the prerequisites and tries to avoid too many collisions(which will still happen pretty frequently with such a simple function I believe).

Comment: Bakuriu, you are right. Hashing the id does not work as expected. I will try your proposal but it would require to define __hash__ for the point object only and not for the BaseGeometry class since that class is inherited by other geometric object such as Polygon which have more than 1 point.

Comment: Shapely geometric object have a Well known text property (.wkt) which I will use as hash function until I find a better one